# Special Folders

Tags: c#, installation

I'm copying some files to a special folder when installing. The SpecialFolder path depends on for how the user choosed to install the app: 'Everyone' or 'Just me'.

From C# code I get the special folder path using Environment.GetFolderPath() method but this method always return the special path of the current user. If the user installed the app for everyone I need the path to the 'All Users' folder. How can I get from C# code the right SpecialFolder path?

Comment: What is a question:
How to get "All users" path?
or
How to determine what user selected ("for me"/"for everyone")?

Comment: How to determinate on what user the app is running ('current user' or 'all users') so that can get the right path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

to get all users path use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE")`..than check that folder and user specified folder for your files